# How do I execute a stored procedure in a SQL Agent job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need to run a SQL Job from SQL Server Agent. I am new to SQL Server Job and I want to execute a stored procedure regularly from a SQL Server Job. But I did not find where to specify the executed stored procedure other than copy & paste SQL commands.

Here is my screen snapshot:

[image]

Any ideas how to assign stored procedure to execute in SQL Server Job?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You just need to add this line to the window there:

```
exec (your stored proc name) (and possibly add parameters)
```

What is your stored proc called, and what parameters does it expect?

Comment: Thanks Marc, my store procedure does not have any parameters. It just does some clean-up work to delete all age out records as I asked in the previous question. In my sample, I just need to enter "exec [dbo].[MyStoreProcedureName]", correct?

Comment: Database context too: Change the Database to "MyDB" or specify the stored proc as EXEC Mydb.dbo.MyProcname

Comment: Depending on the schema you may use something like: USE <databaseName> exec (your stored proc name) (and possibly add parameters)

Answer (score 3):

As Marc says, you run it exactly like you would from the command line. See [Creating SQL Server Agent Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx) on MSDN.