# Executing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 using SQL Agent

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I'm new to SQL Server and I've been looking through this thread: [how to execute a stored procedure in a SQL Agent job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216272/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-a-sql-agent-job) .

I'm posting a new question as to not bump a 5 year old question.

I have a stored procedure called `dbo.Test_CreateCombinedLeads` as far as I know it does not require any additional parameters.

(I am unable to post pictures yet)

Would using this line of code in the command section (as seen question link)

```
exec [dbo].[Test_CreateCombinedLeads]
```

run my stored procedure or would I need more?

(Note: I do have the database dropdown set to the one the store procedure comes from)

Comment: what makes you feel this would not be a duplicate of the question you linked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute a stored procedure in a SQL Agent job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216272/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-a-sql-agent-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would execute your procedure as long as you set it to execute from correct databes in the agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line:

```
use [your database name]
```

before your exec command.