# SSMS exporting stored procedure results into a .csv file and scheduling it at the 12th working day of each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, scheduled-tasks, export-to-csv

i am new to stackoverflow.
I have a task. It requires to scheduling the result of the below stored procedures. at each 12th working day of a month.

Any idea of how to let it work?

````
DECLARE @DATA_RIF AS nvarchar(8) = N'',
        @NOMEJOB AS nvarchar(8) = N'';
--as
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM TMP_BANCHECDSCVADVANOPD
           WHERE CONVERT(datetime, DATA_RIF, 103) <> @DATA_RIF)
OR EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM TMP_CDS_CVA_DVA_CSA_SI
           WHERE CONVERT(datetime, COMPUTE_DATE, 103) <> @DATA_RIF)
    RAISERROR('Presenza date diverse da quella richiesta', 15, 1);

SELECT 'DATA_RIF' AS DATA_RIF,
       'OWNER' AS OWNER,
       'NDG_CONTROPARTE' AS NDG_CONTROPARTE,
       'DESCRIZIONE' AS DESCRIZIONE,
       'ACC_GROUP' AS ACC_GROUP,
       'ACC_AREA' AS ACC_AREA,
       'IDENT' AS IDENT,
       'FULL_FAIR_VALUE' AS FULL_FAIR_VALUE,
       'VALUTAZIONE' AS VALUTAZIONE,
       'MATURITY' AS MATURITY,
       'BUCKET' AS BUCKET,
       'VITA_RESIDUA' AS VITA_RESIDUA,
       'CDS' AS CDS,
       'CDS_A' AS CDS_A,
       'CDS_B' AS CDS_B,
       'CVA_Cont_Unilaterale' AS CVA_Cont_Unilaterale,
       'CVA' AS CVA,
       'CVA_A' AS CVA_A,
       'CVA_B' AS CVA_B
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONVERT(varchar, DATA_RIF, 103) AS DATA_RIF,
       OWNER,
       CAST(CONVERT(bigint, NDG_CONTROPARTE) AS varchar) AS NDG_CONTROPARTE,
       DESCRIZIONE,
       ACC_GROUP,
       ACC_AREA,
       IDENT,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(FULL_FAIR_VALUE AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(VALUTAZIONE AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       CONVERT(varchar(10), DATA_FINE, 103) AS MATURITY,
       CAST(TC AS varchar) AS BUCKET,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(MATURITY AS numeric(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ',') AS VITA_RESIDUA,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(ROUND(CDS, 3) AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(ROUND(CDS_A, 3) AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(ROUND(CDS_B, 3) AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_CONT_UNILATERAL AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL_A AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL_B AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ',')
FROM dbo.TMP_BANCHECDSCVADVANOPD
WHERE OWNER IN ('BANCO', 'BANCA ALETTI', 'BANCA AKROS', 'BPM SPA')
  AND CONVERT(datetime, DATA_RIF, 103) = @DATA_RIF
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONVERT(varchar, COMPUTE_DATE, 103) AS DATA_RIF,
       BANCA,
       CAST(CONVERT(bigint, NDG) AS varchar) AS NDG,
       CONTROPARTE,
       ACC_GROUP,
       ACC_AREA,
       IDENT_PV,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(FULL_FAIR_VALUE AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(VALUTAZIONE AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       CONVERT(varchar(10), MATURITY, 103) AS MATURITY,
       CAST(TC AS varchar) AS BUCKET,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST((ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DD, @DATA_RIF, MATURITY) / CAST(365 AS float), 0)) AS numeric(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ',') AS VITA_RESIDUA,
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CDS AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CDS_A AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CDS_B AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_CONT_UNILATERAL AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL_A AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ','),
       REPLACE(CAST(CAST(CVA_UNILATERAL_B AS decimal(18, 8)) AS varchar), '.', ',')
FROM dbo.TMP_CDS_CVA_DVA_CSA_SI
WHERE BANCA IN ('BANCO', 'BANCA', 'BANCHE', 'BANCHI')
  AND CONVERT(datetime, COMPUTE_DATE, 103) = @DATA_RIF;```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server stored procedure to export Select Result to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773962/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-export-select-result-to-csv)

Comment: I see, but I would need the exporting at the 12th working day of each month.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216272/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-a-sql-agent-job